# What does this format mean T00:00:00.000Z?

Tags: javascript, time, timezone, timestamp, format

Can someone, please, explain this type of format in javascript

```
 T00:00:00.000Z
```

And how to parse it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: `T` means "time", and usually separates the date from the time component.  `Z` means the value is in terms of [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)

Comment: A date time that ends in Z is also called Zulu Time.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

It's a part of [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date representation. It's incomplete because a complete date representation in this pattern should also contains the date:

```
2015-03-04T00:00:00.000Z //Complete ISO-8601 date
```

If you try to parse this date as it is you will receive an `Invalid Date` error:

```
new Date('T00:00:00.000Z'); // Invalid Date
```

So, I guess the way to parse a timestamp in this format is to concat with any date

```
new Date('2015-03-04T00:00:00.000Z'); // Valid Date
```

Then you can extract only the part you want (timestamp part)

```
var d = new Date('2015-03-04T00:00:00.000Z');
console.log(d.getUTCHours()); // Hours
console.log(d.getUTCMinutes());
console.log(d.getUTCSeconds());
```

Comment: Close - you should use `getUTCHours`, `getUTCMinutes`, and `getUTCSeconds`.  Otherwise, you're imparting the behavior of the local time zone, which will yield different results depending on which time zone, and on which date you pick - due to DST.

Answer (score 19):

i suggest you use `moment.js` for this. In moment.js you can:

```
var localTime = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'); // store localTime
var proposedDate = localTime + "T00:00:00.000Z";
```

now that you have the right format for a time, parse it if it's valid:

```
var isValidDate = moment(proposedDate).isValid();
// returns true if valid and false if it is not.
```

and to get time parts you can do something like:

```
var momentDate = moment(proposedDate)
var hour = momentDate.hours();
var minutes = momentDate.minutes();
var seconds = momentDate.seconds();

// or you can use `.format`:
console.log(momentDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss A Z"));
```

More info about momentjs http://momentjs.com/

Comment: You should be able to parse this directly in the moment constructor with an appropriate format string.  (moment will assume the current date if it's not part of the value.)  Also, you might consider `moment.utc(...)` so the resulting value is in the same UTC zone as the original value.

Comment: can you tell me how can we convert back to the original date version T00:00:00.000Z from the formated date version?

Comment: Are you use this result will give you T00:00:00.000Z format?

Comment: As of 2023 i would suggest you use Luxon instead of moment. Moment is no longer in active developpement.

Answer (score 16):

As one person may have already suggested,

I passed the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date string directly to moment like so...

```
moment.utc('2019-11-03T05:00:00.000Z').format('MM/DD/YYYY')
```

or

```
moment('2019-11-03T05:00:00.000Z').utc().format('MM/DD/YYYY')
```

either of these solutions will give you the same result.

```
console.log(moment('2019-11-03T05:00:00.000Z').utc().format('MM/DD/YYYY')) // 11/3/2019
```

More info about momentjs http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Would be good to also link and recommend the usage of [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) javascript library clearly while explaining the code above.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24496195)

Comment: @PhilTune you are right, i think my brain was moving so quick that I technically was replying to comment and not the question

Answer (score 1):

Please use DateTimeFormatter `ISO_DATE_TIME = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;`
instead of `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")` or any pattern

This fixed my problem Below

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-12-18T19:00:00.000Z' could not be parsed at index 10

Comment: It's solved my problem with time convert from string type to OffsetDateTime

Answer (score 1):

Since someone asked how to implement it :

Its easy using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) :

```
// install using yarn
yarn add moment
// or install using npm 
npm i moment
```

then you can do like this to extract the date according to the format you want :

```
import 'moment' from moment;

let isoDate = "2021-09-19T05:30:00.000Z";

let newDate =  moment.utc(isoDate).format('MM/DD/YY');
console.log('converted date', newDate); // 09/23/21 
 
let newDate2 = moment.utc(isoDate).format("MMM Do, YYYY");
console.log('converted date', newDate2); // Sept 24, 2021
```

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers have already solved this. What I also found helpful is this timestamp converter, which gives a quick way to play around with the ISO 8601 and other timestamps. It'll help you decode and encode a particular time:

https://time.lol/

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems, I solved it by converting the date/time, before sending to the server, using:

**Example:** (UTC Brazil) I typed "**15**/12/2020 **22:30**:00" and it sent: '2020-12-**16**T**01:30**:00.000Z'.
You convert using:

```
var date = new Date('2020-11-06T01:30:00.000Z');
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString());
console.log(date.toLocaleString());
console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString());
```