# Nodejs-xlsx: reading time issue

Tags: node.js, xlsx

I am trying to read an excel file that has two columns 'Start Time' and 'End Time', and the data is in the form '8:00 AM','10:15 AM', etc.

The value in the field is **8:30 AM**

When I try to read the excel file using `xlsx` module with no options specified

`var workbook = XLSX.readFile('sample-excel.xlsx');`

I get this.

[image: output]

When I try this

`var workbook = XLSX.readFile('sample-excel.xlsx',{cellDates:true});`

I get this.

[image: output]

Please help, I want to store the text as it is that is `json = {time:'8:30 AM'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time field in excel is of date type, so you need to parse the output.

Here is the code to parse date time

```
const moment = require('moment')

var momentDate = moment('1899-12-30T03:00:00.000Z')

var hour = momentDate.hours();
var minutes = momentDate.minutes();
var seconds = momentDate.seconds();
console.log(hour,minutes,seconds);

// or you can use `.format`:
console.log(momentDate.format("hh:mm:ss A"));
```

You refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28949911/what-does-this-format-means-t000000-000z) for details