# Javascript date result console is not matched with MySQL result

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

i run a query which is giving me following results

[image]

but when i am trying to console it using JavaScript this is giving me one minus date from the results.

```
[
  RowDataPacket { total: 0, log_date: 2020-12-04T18:30:00.000Z },
  RowDataPacket { total: 0, log_date: 2020-12-07T18:30:00.000Z },
  RowDataPacket { total: 0, log_date: 2020-12-11T18:30:00.000Z }
]
```

why this is happening. both mysql and console output are on  local.

Comment: The dates in your JS are in UTC representation (`Z` is for Zulu time)

Comment: How to fix this issue please

Comment: log_date: 2020-12-04 in JavaScript but in mysql  log_date: 2020-12-05

Comment: Look the time in JavaScript and in the query in addition to the date - the difference must be less than a day, it must be some hours according to your time zone. And decide what value is accurate and what is wrong. PS. What is precise `log_date` datatype?

Comment: Possible solution - convert date to a string during retrieve (`SELECT CAST(log_date AS CHAR) AS log_date, ...`). Timeshift won't be applied to the string data.

Comment: @Akina . Awesome man.. Thanks you are saver..

Comment: Thanks @Akina.. will it work on any timezone

Comment: This code not depends on a timezone.

Answer (score 0):

here is might be an explanation: [What does this format means T00:00:00.000Z?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28949911/what-does-this-format-means-t000000-000z).

in your case, you may try:

```
var d = new Date('2020-12-04T18:30:00.000Z');
console.log(d.getDay()); // Day is 5.
```