# Extract datetime from string with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an AJAX request that returns an array, in this array I capture the created_at from my database and it comes in the following format:

Code:

```
success: function(response){
     let data = response;
     date = data[0][`created_at`];

     console.log(date);
}
```

log:

```
2022-08-25T18:44:48.000000Z
```

I need to split this string into two variables (date and time), what is the best way?

Comment: how do you want it split

Comment: What is the format you want the date to be?

Comment: I need the date and time separated into two different strings (date = XX-XX-XXXX and time = XX:XX:XX)

Comment: `.split('T')` ?

Comment: Great but how do I remove the .000000Z from the end of the hour?

Comment: Just split it again. See [String.prototype.split](https://developer.mozilla.org//docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it like this,

```
success: function(response){
     let data = response;
     date = data[0][`created_at`];
     
     // date.split('T') - this will create an array like ['2022-08-25', '18:44:48.000000Z']
     // const [date, time] - this is Array destructuring in action.

     const [date, time] = date.split('T') 
     
     // date - '2022-08-25'
     // time - '18:44:48.000000Z'

     console.log(date, time)
}
```

checkout this: [What does this format mean T00:00:00.000Z?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28949911/what-does-this-format-mean-t000000-000z)

also checkout: [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 0):

```
Let date = new Date(data[0][`created_at`]);
Console.log(date.format('dd/mm/yy'))
```

Try to install moment.js